# CodeIgniter: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting the above error, is there any built in support for a stack trade in code igniter?  I have an infinite loop somewhere I'm trying to figure out where it is...

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit

Comment: If CI replaces the default error handler and slurps up line number and filename, then reinstantiate a workaround with `set_error_handler("var_dump");` early in your script. Otherwise use the xdebug profiler.

Comment: Better answer than mine!

Comment: That only tells me how to increase it, I don't want to increase it, I want to find the loop

Comment: Sorry. The problem is you're probably using var_export() somewhere. It doesn't stop on infinite nested objects (which is common in some frameworks). Try using var_dump() or print_r() instead.

Comment: I'm not using var_dump, print_r or var_export anywhere

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion below?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the xDebug plugin for PHP for the functionality you seek:

http://www.xdebug.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you use hmvc, check if you have not loaded something in the wrong way, i.e, $this->load->module() instead of $this->load->model().
I faced the same issue and that was the cause of that message.

Comment: welcome to SO! Notice its a 10 years old question. Make sure the answer still relevent nowadays.