# Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! with ionCube loader

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, ioncube

I am getting Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! with ionCube loader.And I don't want to uninstall IonCube.So what should I do ?

Comment: Do you have xdebug turned on?

Comment: I had it earlier,now I have removed it.But it is still not working .

Comment: Are you sure you removed it? Did you restarted Apache?

Comment: yea.I removed xdebug.DLL also

Comment: run a `phpinfo()` to see if xdebug is 100% unloaded.

Comment: Checked .It is 100 % unloaded

Comment: if use WAMP, note that disabling xdebug in php.ini does NOT always work; same applies to extending level of allowed nesting; a bug a guess; SOLUTION: go to php.ini and comment out php_xdebug-???.dll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some solutions

- Rewrite your code to make sure you never reach 100 nested calls
- Raise limit on `xdebug`: `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200` in `php.ini`

Comment: I dont have Xdebug .
And why to edit code ,when it is due to some extension like ioncube

Comment: I don't think IonCube has anything to do with this error ..

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor)

Comment: check what? Is that the exact screen you get?

Comment: In the question,it is mention that it is may be due to ioncube

Comment: ioncobe doesn't have `max_nesting_level`, it's `Zend/XDebug`