# Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached, aborting

Tags: php, apache, wamp, xdebug

I am using a CMS(which was bought, it's not nulled). My problem is that sometimes it gets really slow, and everyone who uses it has to refresh it a couple of times, or wait like 10-15 seconds until it shows up.

I've done some research, I have Xdebug enabled(if I disable it, apache will use all of the Memory_limit, and the CPU will get up to 100%), I tried using Win32DisableAcceptEx aswell, but that did not do the trick. Tried uninstalling wamp and installing latest version of it, that didn't work either.

I've been searching for days now, asking support from the guys who made this CMS, they did not reply. If I change the nesting level to whatever number, it's going to do the same thing. If I disable Xdebug, now matter how big memory_limit I put, it's still going to reach it. Honestly I have no idea what's happening. I've been using this CMS for a year now, and never had this problem. Here's one part of apache_error.log :

```
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.852157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached, aborting! in C:\\wamp\\www\\system\\database\\drivers\\mysqli\\mysqli_driver.php on line 200, referer: http://oblivion-wow.com/application/themes/crusader_theme/css/cms.css
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.852157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP Stack trace:, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\index.php:0, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   2. require_once() C:\\wamp\\www\\index.php:228, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   3. News->__construct() C:\\wamp\\www\\system\\core\\CodeIgniter.php:1, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   4. MX_Controller->__construct() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\modules\\news\\controllers\\news.php:11, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   5. Template->show404() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\third_party\\MX\\Controller.php:67, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   6. Template->view() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\libraries\\template.php:502, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   7. Template->handleNormalPage() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\libraries\\template.php:139, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   8. Template->loadSideboxes() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\libraries\\template.php:156, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP   9. Custom->__construct() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\libraries\\template.php:334, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP  10. MX_Controller->__construct() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\modules\\sidebox_custom\\controllers\\custom.php:9, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP  11. Template->show404() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\third_party\\MX\\Controller.php:67, referer: same
[Sun Nov 17 10:09:59.853157 2013] [:error] [pid 4884:tid 1548] [client 79.138.165.229:50638] PHP  12. Template->view() C:\\wamp\\www\\application\\libraries\\template.php:502, referer: same
```

This is the mysqli_driver.php : http://pastebin.com/c4MkY5st

Comment: I forgot to mention that this topic was one of my main sources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor?rq=1

Comment: MySQLi is not the problem. You have an infinite loop in your code - the backtrace suggests that steps 4-9 are being repeated. Inspect your code, figure out why `MX_Controller::construct` calls into `Template::show404`, and add some sanity checks to fall back to a simple error page if you have to handle an error while already handling an error.

Comment: Well, this helped me a LOT. I found the controller.php file, and deleted rows from 6-8 : http://pastebin.com/v7KgE1w4 Thanks a bunch for your help!