# Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! Route Model Binding

Tags: laravel-4

My route file

```
Route::model('rank', 'Rank');
Route::resource('rank', 'AdminRankController');
```

My Controller file

```
public function show($rank)
{
    return $rank;
}
```

This give me error Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Any Help will be appreciated . Earlier It was working . But My composer update ruined all.

Please note if I change it like

```
Route::model('ranks', 'Rank');
```

It is working but no database query runs to fetch the corresponding row

Comment: did you search on google ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor

Comment: yes .. I have xdebug installed . even I increased the limit also . but this is not working either.. I have been googling for more than 6 hrs :-(

Comment: OMG !!! These guys will drive anyone crazy... I kicked Ardent away and now it is working .

This one 
"laravel/framework": "~4.1@stable"

didn't worked for me . please anyone with better solution ..

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2812

Comment: It's being happened because of too much nesting of function calls, functions are being called/chained from one to another and `heap` memory is getting overflowed so, it's not a good solution to use something like `xdebug.max_nesting_level=500`, most probably `debug_backtrace()` can help to find out the function nesting, try to debug with `xdebug` or leave `Ardent`.

Comment: It should be `stack` not `heap`, it was a mistake.