# Next element in array

Tags: php

I create such function for find next element from my array

```
protected function getProject($array, $slug, $next = 999)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $project)
    {
        if($project->getSlug() == $slug) {
            return $this->getNextProject($array, $slug, $key + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

But in result i have error "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting". I know that there is a getSlug() isset. Please, help me solve this problem

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor

Comment: @Toretto do you think my logic is correct?

Comment: if i var_dump($next) i get `int 999
int 2
int 2
int 2
int 2
int 2
....
`
It's correct but when $key =2 , it must return $project->getSlug();

Comment: Pretty sure you have an infinite loop.  You are never changing the value of `$slug` (or the `$array`), so when you run this, you're gonna loop the `$array`, and find an element where `$project->getSlug() == $slug`.  Then you're gonna call `getNextProject` again and run the loop again and call `getNextProject` again... and so on.  You need to re-think your logic.  Recursion only works when you can actually stop at one point.

Comment: You have multiple return statement which is not correct.

Comment: @Toretto: How is that "not correct"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way it's create new function, witch look like this:

```
public function yourAction($array, $key)
{
    foreach($array as $index => $project) {
        if($index == $key) {
            return $project->getProduct();
        }
    }
}
```

And then usa like

```
if($project->getProduct() == $slug) {
    $nextProduct = $this->yourAction($array, $key + 1)
    return $nextProject;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't your 1st loop just be replaced with `return $array[$key]->getProduct();`?  Why do you need a loop?  Also, didn't he want the *next* element?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the limit of xdebug in `php.ini`
For example, making nesting level limit to 300:
`xdebug.max_nesting_level=300`

You can also comment out this line in `php.ini` to remove limiting constrain:
`";xdebug.max_nesting_level"`

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop/infinite recursion going on here.

```
foreach($array as $key => $project)
{
    if($project->getSlug() == $slug) {
        return $this->getNextProject($array, $slug, $key + 1);
    }

    // ...
}
```

If there are any `$array` elements that match the condition `$project->getSlug() == $slug`, it will call `getNextProject()` again, which will run this `foreach` again thus calling `getNextProject()` again... and so on.

You need to reorder/re-think your logic here.  You can try to move the `if($next != 999) {` to the *top* of the `foreach`.

Try this:

```
protected function getNextProject($array, $slug, $next = 999)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $project)
    {
        if($next != 999 && $next == $key) {
            return $project->getSlug();
        }
        if($project->getSlug() == $slug) {
            return $this->getNextProject($array, $slug, $key + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Or better yet, you can just do this with *one* loop and no recursion:

```
protected function getNextProject($array, $slug)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $project)
    {
        if($project->getSlug() == $slug && isset($array[$key+1])){
            return $array[$key+1]->getSlug();
        }
    }
}
```

Just find the 1st element that matches the `$slug`, then get the next one and return its slug.