# Laravel 5.2 - Can't add 'web' middleware to home page with a controller

Tags: php, laravel, router, middleware, laravel-5

When user has logged in, home page does not show logged details. Only show login and register links instead. To resolve that I've added `web` middleware in router file.

This code works fine :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

Changing this code as follow I got an error when user logged in

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Error : **FatalErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 314:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!**

Recently I've run the `composer update`

So what should i do to add this controller for home page in router ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it show the stack trace ? It happens when some function is being called recursively.
quoting the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor).

Increase the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level in your php.ini: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Comment: I went through your link and finally found the solution. Added `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);` in top of the index.php