# PHP explode in array

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering is it possible to convert the following array:

```
Array (
    "2016-03-03 19:17:59",
    "2016-03-03 19:20:54",
    "2016-05-03 19:12:37"
)
```

Into this:

```
Array (
    "2016-03-03",
    "2016-03-03",
    "2016-05-03"
)
```

Without creating any loops?

Comment: Gonna ask the obvious question. What's wrong with loops....?

Comment: *"Without creating any loops?"* **NO.** At the end you need to change each array element so you have to loop over the array. Just search how to convert one date format into another and how to apply a function to each array element.

Comment: an odd number of questions ask: how to do X without (insert basic php\programming term\function here)

Comment: @nogad there is a simple explanation: they have read somewhere that "loops are slow in php".

Comment: ok, but is  is basically meaningless.

Comment: There's even a simpler explanation (Occam's Razor anyone?)... the homework says "do not use loops" :D

Comment: why set homework that has no basis in reality? oh right i remember school now :-)

Comment: i expect the OP not to care but benchmarking of 10 million iterations gives an average of 23 seconds for foreach() vs array_map of 30 seconds

Comment: http://ideone.com/KzmfKd =23 seconds. http://ideone.com/RVGgTm =30 seconds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no explicit loops, if you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), although internally it loops:

```
function format_date($val) {
  $v = explode(" ", $val);
  return $v[0];
}
$arr = array_map("format_date", $arr);
```

From the PHP Manual:

> `array_map()` returns an array containing all the elements of `array1` after applying the `callback` function to each one. The number of parameters that the `callback` function accepts should match the number of arrays passed to the `array_map()`.

Also, when you are dealing with Dates, the right way to do is as follows:

```
return date("Y-m-d", strtotime($val));
```

---

The simple way, using loops is to use a `foreach()`:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $date)
  $arr[$key] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

This is the most simplest looping way I can think of considering the `index` to be anything.

---

**Input:**

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "2016-03-03 19:17:59",
    "2016-03-03 19:20:54",
    "2016-05-03 19:12:37"
);
function format_date($val) {
  $v = explode(" ", $val);
  return $v[0];
}
$arr = array_map("format_date", $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-03-03
    [1] => 2016-03-03
    [2] => 2016-05-03
)
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/r9AyYV**

Comment: Hm, a call to `explode()` with only a single argument?

Comment: Although this is still loops internally I would expect, I suppose as long as OP can't see them they won't mind :P

Comment: some one benchmark this against a foreach loop and explode

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is much better and faster solution than looping through the entire array.

Comment: "Faster solution". Probably, but I doubt by much ;)

Comment: @JonStirling The difference between `array_map` and `foreach` will be negligible and since this looks like an academic one, I don't think there'll be much problem. What say?

Comment: @Beqa it DOES loop the array, just because you dont see it, doesn't mean it doesn't happen

Comment: @PraveenKumar Agreed. Just don't want OP to be under their apparent preconception that OMG loops are bad.

Comment: @nogad I added that in my answer mate.

Comment: @JonStirling Sure, but I also added the info in the first line.

Comment: suer but the OP does not seem to get it

Comment: @PraveenKumar I didn't downvote, but your first answer revision was a very poor one. What I think you can improve is: 1) Explain that `array_map()` also loops through the array 2) Maybe also show how to properly convert one date format into another instead of that "hack" for this specific format. 3) Explain what exactly does `array_map()`.

Comment: @Rizier123 yea, sure... I will update them now... Will be helpful for future users...

Comment: @Rizier123 Check it out.. How does that look?

Comment: It looks like a mess guys, when some of you make a really useless comments.. If anyone has a better solution, please post it, even if it's done by loops.

Comment: Looks better. (@Beqa Since you have to do something to *every* array element you won't get around with looping through the array, as already explained to you, if you now write the loop your own or just call a function. And probably more times than you think is a simple foreach loop the fastest, since it doesn't have the overhead from a function call.)

Comment: @Beqa no its not, i just benchmarked it, array_map vs foreach() is slower (10million iterations, 23 seconds vs 30)

Comment: @Beqa Added a minimal `foreach` solution as well.

Comment: @nogad Great. Thanks. Better than what?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use map:

```
function first10($s) {
    return substr($s, 0, 10);
}

$result = array_map("first10", $yourArray);
```

**WARNING**: this is a good solution only if you are sure that the date format does not change, in other words the first 10 characters must contain the date.

Comment: @PraveenKumar validation is not the subject of a question

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks, I added a warning so he knows where the limits of this solution are.

Answer (score 1):

[Praveen Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948955/1028804) is probably the better solution but there is a way to do with what wouldn't really been seen as a loop. instead you use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

```
function explodeNoLoop($array,$delim,$index=0)
{
    $returnArr = array();
    if(isset($array[$index]))
    {
        $expldoed = explode($delim,$array[$index]);
        array_push($returnArr,$expldoed[0]);
    }
    if(isset($array[$index+1]))
    {
        $returnArr = array_merge($returnArr,explodeNoLoop($array,$delim,$index+1));
    }
    return $returnArr;
}

$myArr = array (
    "2016-03-03 19:17:59",
    "2016-03-03 19:20:54",
    "2016-05-03 19:12:37"
);

var_dump(explodeNoLoop($myArr," "));
```

[example](https://repl.it/DsCX)

How this code works is that with the function we explode the array at the index provided by the function parameter and add this to our returning array. Then we check if there is a value set at the next index which is +1 of the index we passed into the function. If it exists then we call the function again with the new index with the same array and delimiter. We then merge the results of this with our returner array and then return that.

However, with this one should be careful of [nest level errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8656089/1028804) where you excursively call a function too many times, like looking into the reflection of a mirror in a mirror.

Comment: Woooooaaah!!! Wow! But recursion seems to be an overkill for the current situation. LoL. We are thinking creatively.