# laravel 5.2 mail not working

Tags: php, laravel, email, mamp-pro

I have laravel 5.2 with mamp pro in my mac. I work localhost, and i try to send email to mailtrap but is not work i have this error

```
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=MyuserName
MAIL_PASSWORD=MyPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

in my controller

```
Mail::send('emails.test', ['user' => 'test'], function ($m) {
        $m->from('from@example.com', 'Your Application');

        $m->to('from@example.com')->subject('Your Reminder!');
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution for "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!" in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding the following code in `bootstrap/autoload.php` file. It increases the `xdebug.max_nesting_level` to 200.

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
```

If this doesn't solve then try to increase the level by 300 or 400.

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust your `php.ini` file to something like 200, this will cure the issue

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**.env File:-**

MAIL_DRIVER=mail

**app/mail.php File:-**

'driver' => 'mail'

**Controller file:-**

Mail::send('emails.test', ['user' => 'test'], function ($m) {

```
    $m->from('from@example.com', 'Your Application');

    $m->to('from@example.com')->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```