# Laravel Mail:: inside function creates error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am making my own package.

I simplified the code to explain the weird error.
I have a simple method inside a simple controller. First, i am sending an email (printing in laravel.log) and works fine.

```
public function signup(){

    Mail::send('vendor.proto.register.emails.proto-register-new-account', [], function ($m) {
        $m->from('noreply@test.com', 'Hello');
        $m->to('sfs@dgf.c', 'pepe')->subject('Test. Congratulations, your account was created');
    });
    return view('view path');
}
```

But when i want to move the Mail:: to a private method like this.

```
public function signup(){
    $this->sendNotification2();
    return view('view path');
}


public function sendNotification2(){
    Mail::send('vendor.proto.register.emails.proto-register-new-account', [], function ($m) {
        $m->from('noreply@test.com', 'Hello');
        $m->to('sfs@dgf.c', 'pepe')->subject('Test. Congratulations, your account was created');
    });
}
```

It crash an print the error 
`FatalErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 373:` `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`

Is it a bug? or i am doing something wrong ?

**Solution.**

Googling i found this solution. Notice i am using laravel 5.2 and php 5.6.7
Add in `bootstrap\autoload.php` this code `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);` and it fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution for "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor)

Comment: @BagusTesa It could be the solution but the problem is more with laravel than the php configuration.

Comment: conversely, i think its something with php since it works in the original location but then fails **when you move** the code into another **function** that clearly increase the **depth of function calls**. and as additional note, the cause for deep function call is.. you are using Laravel which in turn uses Symfony.

Comment: @BagusTesa well. Maybe u where right. Searching on google i found it.  add in `bootstrap\autoload.php` this code `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);` and it fix the problem.