# Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! at Magento save config

Tags: php, magento, mage

So as I try to save my configuration from **System->Configuration->Save Config** I get an error saying:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
In Mage.php on line 412.
And in lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 125.
```

Mage.php line 412:

```
public static function getConfig()
{
    return self::$_config;
}
```

Autoload.php line 125:

```
public function destroy()
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_saveCollectedStat();
    }
}
```

I did some research but couldn't find much.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey check you php.ini file.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your bootsrap.php

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 500);
```

Or if you have access to your php.ini add in your php.ini file

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
```

The [500] is not required you can set also 200, 300, etc.