# Max function nesting level inject Doctrine Repository in Normalizer

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

When I try to inject a Doctrine repository (as ServiceEntityRepository) in a custom Normalizer I have this error `Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!`

My customer normalizer:

```
class GroupNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
/**
 * @var GroupRepository
 */
private $groupRepository;

public function __construct(GroupRepository $groupRepository)
{
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
}

public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
...
```

And the repository:

```
class GroupRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{

public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, Group::class);
}
```

I am using Symfony 3.4.

Do you have any idea to avoid this error?

**Edit**

My stack trace
[image]

Comment: Can you post here the full error stack trace please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution for "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor)

Comment: @HieuLe the full stack error is too long to post here (it's Symfony error page in fact)

Comment: The 2 snippets of code you posted looks allright, there must be an issue somewhere else. For that we would need to have a peak at the stack trace.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the beginning of the stack trace

Comment: Can't it be an issue of circular reference ? if it is a custom normalizer, maybe it does not set a limit ?