# how to solve Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting?

Tags: php, nested-loops

I am trying to do nested categories main menus and submenus separetly.
it was giving error :

> Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! ?

I have tried everything inthis answer: [Solution for "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor)

But didnt work for me, now my page keep loading and keep adding black list dots to the page.

Here is code I think I am doing something wrong in codes but cant find where.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$stmt =$pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $rows = $stmt->fetch();
}else{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
unset($stmt);
$items = $rows;
echo "<ul>";
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item['parent_id'] == 0){
        echo "<li>".$item['cat_name'];
        $id = $item['cat_id'];
        sub($items, $id);
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

function sub($items, $id){
echo "<ul>";
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item['parent_id'] == $id){
            echo "<li>".$item['cat_name'];
            sub($items, $item['cat_id']);
        echo "</li>";
        }
    }
echo "</ul>";
}
```

I am using wamp server on local.

**EDIT :** Here is mytable structure, and I am usningphp 7.2.18

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seo_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `place` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`cat_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here i the data inmy data base:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`cat_id`, `cat_name`, `seo_url`, `parent_id`, `place`) VALUES
(1, 'Ana Sayfa', '#', 0, 1),
(2, 'Tutorials', '#', 0, 1),
(3, 'Java', 'java', 6, 1),
(4, 'Liferay', 'liferay', 3, 1),
(5, 'Frameworks', '#', 0, 1),
(6, 'JSF', 'jsf', 5, 1),
(7, 'Struts', 'struts', 5, 1),
(8, 'Spring', 'spring', 6, 1),
(9, 'Hibernate', 'hibernate', 6, 1),
(10, 'Webservices', '#', 0, 1),
(11, 'REST', 'rest', 10, 1),
(12, 'SOAP', 'soap', 10, 1),
(13, 'Contact', 'contact', 0, 1),
(14, 'About', 'about', 0, 1),
(15, 'TEST-TEST-TEST', 'test', 5, 1),
(16, 'TEST2', 'test2', 15, 1);
```

Comment: Can you share the `$items` structure and some sample data?

Comment: Thanks for answer, added what you need to question. @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have one issue in your code, which is that you should be using `$stmt->fetchAll()` to fetch all the data, rather than `$stmt->fetch()` which will only fetch one row. However your list generation code works fine (https://3v4l.org/HPP3s) although it does produce some empty `<ul></ul>` structures. You can simplify this code and remove those by using this function. By passing `$parent_id = 0` for the first iteration we avoid the need to have two separate blocks of code as you do.

```
function draw_menu($items, $parent_id) {
    echo "\n<ul>\n";
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            echo "<li>" . $item['cat_name'];
            // any children?
            if (count(array_keys(array_column($items, 'parent_id'), $item['cat_id']))) {
                draw_menu($items, $item['cat_id']);
            }
            echo "</li>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

draw_menu($items, 0);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TT7nb)

The output of this function for your sample data is as below:

```html
<ul>
<li>Ana Sayfa</li>
<li>Tutorials</li>
<li>Frameworks
<ul>
<li>JSF
<ul>
<li>Java
<ul>
<li>Liferay</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Spring</li>
<li>Hibernate</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Struts</li>
<li>TEST-TEST-TEST
<ul>
<li>TEST2</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Webservices
<ul>
<li>REST</li>
<li>SOAP</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>About</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Got you thanks, the menu I have in site requires two different block like menus and submenus differently to add html  checkbox etc, I will try your code.

Comment: @dilekkoç fair enough - that wasn't clear from your code and I always love to simplify! :-) Note that you might be able to achieve that requirement using CSS using `::before` or `::after` based on the class of the menu item

Comment: I need to read more about fetch and fetchAll .lol thank you so much.