# Laravel 8: Class 'App\Policies\Gate' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, policy

I have defined a Policy named `UserPolicy` which goes like this:

```
class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        if(Gate::allows('edit', $user)){
            return view('admin.users.edit' , compact('user'));
        }
        abort(403);
    }
}
```

And at `AuthServiceProvider.php`, I have called it like this:

```
protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        User::class => UserPolicy::class
    ];
```

Then at the Blade, I added this:

```
@can('edit', $user)
   <a href="{{ route('users.edit' , ['user' => $user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
@endcan
```

But now, I get this error:

> Class 'App\Policies\Gate' not found

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you have not imported `Gate` facade in `UserPolicy` class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
```

Comment: Great! But now I get `Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! `

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor

Comment: @tejoslaeslio your gate needs to return true or false to indicate if a user is authorised to perform a task. You're returning the view (which itself calls the gate again)

Comment: @apokryfos So what is the proper way

Comment: it depends what you need the gate to do. The idea is when you have the line `@can('edit', $user)`  to deremine whether the current user can perform the `edit` action on the parameter `$user`. The gate needs to return `true` if the current user can edit `$user` and false otherwise. That really depends what your edit policy is. Maybe you need to check if the current user is the same as `$user` or if the current user is a user administrator or something like that