# Receiving Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! when trying to make a recursion script with PHP

Tags: php, xml, nested

```
public function action_xmlread()
{
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('new.xml');

        foreach($xml->body as $b)
        {
            foreach ($b->node as $node) {
                $this->dig($node);
            }
        }
}
public function dig($node)
{
    if(isset($node->tit) && !isset($node->url))
    {
        $this->dig($node);
    }else{
        $this->grabData($node);
    }
}
public function grabData($node)
{
    $category_names = array('userdef1', 'userdef2');

    $url = $node->url;

    $category = '';
    foreach($category_names as $catname)
    {
        if(isset($node->$catname))
        {
            $category = $node->$catname;

            break;
        }
    }

    $keywords = $node->key;
    $title = $node->tit;
    if(empty($url) && empty($category))
    {
        continue;
    }
    $this->saveItem($title, $url, $category, $keywords);
    echo $url . " , category: ". $category;
    echo '<br />';
}
```

When I run xmlread() it dies with:

Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

On the

```
$this->dig($node);
```

Inside the dig() function.. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in infinite recursion, since you are not changing the parameter you are passing to `dig`. Maybe you have to pass the child nodes?

Comment: Thats true, clicked for me now. I tried to change to $this->dig($node[0]) , but still the same errors. I did var_dump($node);
   exit; and got this: http://pastebin.com/dzcSsyv4 , I would like to grabData() on all the [0], [1] etc nodes inside the  public 'node' =>
    array as you can see.. Hope you can help me out thanks!

Comment: Update: I did this: http://pastebin.com/HXnvUyuL and now it works! Although my issue now is that I cant go deeper than one sub-node, which was my main purpose for making this script

Comment: Update: edited to $this->dig($n); Now it works how I wish i believe

Answer (score 1):

To increase your function nesting level you need to edit your php.ini. But maybe your problem is somewhere else.

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293870/326016)