# PHP Error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: mysql, php

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in ...\project\db.php on line 2

My db.php code

```
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","db_user","password");
mysql_select_db("db_name",$db);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: this error seems to be caused by x-debug, there is an answer for this in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Increase the value of `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in your php.ini, [INFO](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level) 
There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor)

Comment: thanks, this worked fine for me. I just used it at the script level for more security like: ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);

Comment: This is not a valid solution, You need to check the code whether the code is wasting request with the db or with other resources.
Your code is somehow misusing the resources.

Comment: I changed mine to 4096, still get that error.. Clearly it must be a bug in the code?

Answer (score 11):

Go into your php.ini configuration file and change the following line:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=100
```

to something like:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting! in Z:\home\localhost\www\clientcms\db.php on line 2

Comment: I'm also getting Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '2000' reached, aborting!

I set `xdebug.max_nesting_level=2000`

Answer (score 1):

mysql_connect will return a boolean therefor :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db("databaseName");
?>
```