# laravel 4 - route with two bound models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to check that `{subcategory}` has parent category `{category}`. How i can get the model of `{category}` in second binding?

I tried `$route->getParameter('category');`. Laravel throws `FatalErrorException` with message "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!".

```
Route::bind('category', function ($value) {
    $category = Category::where('title', $value)->first();
    if (!$category || $category->parent_id) {
        App::abort(404);
    }
    return $category;
});

Route::bind('subcategory', function ($value, $route) {
    if ($value) {
        $category = Category::where('title', $value)->first();
        if ($category) {
            return $category;
        }
        App::abort(404);
    }
});

Route::get('{category}/{subcategory?}', 'CategoriesController@get');
```

Update:

Now i made this, but i think it's not the best solution.

```
Route::bind('category', function ($value) {
    $category = Category::where('title', $value)->whereNull('parent_id')->first();
    if (!$category) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    Route::bind('subcategory', function ($value, $route) use ($category) {
        if ($value) {
            $subcategory = Category::where('title', $value)->where('parent_id', $category->id)->first();
            if (!$subcategory) {
                App::abort(404);
            }

            return $subcategory;
        }
    });

    return $category;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try this and should work, code is self explanatory (ask if need an explanation):

```
Route::bind('category', function ($value) {
    $category = Category::where('title', $value)->first();
    if (!$category || $category->parent_id) App::abort(404);
    return $category;
});

Route::bind('subcategory', function ($value, $route) {
    $category = $route->parameter('category');
    $subcategory = Category::where('title', $value)->whereParentId($category->id);
    return $subcategory->first() ?: App::abort(404); // shortcut of if
});

Route::get('{category}/{subcategory?}', 'CategoriesController@get');
```

**Update:** (As `OP` claimed that, there is no `parameter` method available in `Route` class):

```
/**
 * Get a given parameter from the route.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  mixed  $default
 * @return string
 */
public function getParameter($name, $default = null)
{
    return $this->parameter($name, $default);
}

/**
 * Get a given parameter from the route.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  mixed  $default
 * @return string
 */
public function parameter($name, $default = null)
{
    return array_get($this->parameters(), $name) ?: $default;
}
```

Comment: In Laravel 4 `Route` class don't have `parameter()` method.

Comment: @DmitryGres, There is a `parameter` method in the `Route` class, make sure you checked the right `class`.

Comment: There isn't a `paremeter` method (http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html). When i try laravel throws `FatalErrorException` with message "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::parameter()".

Comment: @DmitryGres, [Check this, Laravel 4.1](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/) and you can use  [getParameter](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html#_getParameter) method as well if you are using older version.

Comment: I tried `$route->getParameter('category');`. Laravel throws `FatalErrorException` with message "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!".

Comment: @DmitryGres, [Maximum function nesting level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit).

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this right now for you, but the closure function receives a $value and $route.
The last one is a instance of '\Illuminate\Routing\Route' (http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html), and perhaps you could use the `getParameter()` method to retrieve some data....

Comment: I tried `$route->getParameter('category');`. Laravel throws `FatalErrorException` with message "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!".

Comment: try `resolveParameter('category')`, if that doesn't work, I give up.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into same issues while trying to auto validate my stories existence inside my Session Model. So, i tried to check my Story model existence inside my Session Model using model bindings.

This is my solution

```
$router->bind('stories', function($value, $route) {
        $routeParameters = $route->parameters();
        $story = Story::where('id', $value)->where('poker_session_id',    $routeParameters['poker_sessions']->id)->first();

        if (!$story) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }

        return $story;
    });
```

You can actually get route parameters using $route->parameters(), which returns an array. In my case, "poker_sessions" key contain an PokerSession Model, which i want.

Please be careful and use this only when you have a /category/{category}/subcategory/{subcategory} url like. Not subcategory without any {category}.

Good luck!.