# explode() and maximum function nesting level

Tags: php, kohana-2

I can found in logs errors like:,
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

The line is:

```
$keys = explode('.', $keys);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you search SO? NO! Not even looked to the right under "Related"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing nesting functions calls limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit)

Comment: That line isn't the reason for the error. You probably have unbounded recursion, and it's just by accident that the 100'th level of call is to `explode`.

Comment: krishna I didn't want now how to increase this number, but I want know relations between explode and this error. Thanks @Barmar that's all I want to know. Can't vote :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xdebug, increase the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level in your php.ini

http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Comment: Any time you are going over 100 nested calls, you almost certainly have an error in a recursive algorithm. Increasing the max nesting level is unlikely to fix the underlying issue.

Comment: you can see pcre.recursion_limit variable. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php