# Yaml parameters not working on symfony/doctrine entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I have a entity called Venues and other called Users. Each Venue has one field called User which is the owner of the venue and is one of the users. On the other side each User has a Venue field, including the original venue where he signed up. So I'm trying to sort out what's the proper yml config.

On the venue.orm.yml file I have

> ```
> manyToOne:
>     user:
>         targetEntity: Users
>         joinColumns:
>                   User:
>                     referencedColumnName: ID
>         inverseJoinColumns:
>                   ID:
>                     referencedColumnName: User
>         orphanRemoval: false
> ```

And on the users.orm.yml I got:

> ```
> manyToOne:
>     venue:
>         targetEntity: Venues
>         joinColumns:
>                   Venue:
>                     referencedColumnName: ID
>         inverseJoinColumns:
>                   ID:
>                     referencedColumnName: Venue
>         orphanRemoval: false
> ```

The app fails silently, stopping the rendering of the view, just when form_start(form).
I'm not able to see the web profiler (as usual) although I'm on dev mode. If I remove the field User from venue, then the render will be ok.
Please let me know what I'm missing since I can't find a proper example under doctrine or symfony docs, and I think that I'm misunderstanding this link http://mnapoli.fr/doctrine-2-yaml-reference/ Thanks in advance ;)

**EDIT**
The cause of the failure was a Memory Exhaust type error so this
issue was at first provisionally solved by increasing the php.ini memory limit to 220MB,but as I need to set it back to 64MB limit, I found that by explicitly declaring all the types and entity options of my formType, the memory overhead was dramatically reduced. In addition I have limited the total options available at some selects, using query builder in the formType. Anyway I'll look forward for any additional action oriented to the memory saving. I'm going to google for any select options lazyloader Symfony component...

Comment: if it fails silently the best way to debug is to fire up the terminal and look into `dev.log`. The easiest way to do so is: `tail -f app/logs/dev.log`

Comment: really a changing game trick ;)  so the result is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1502052/dev.log , and I'm not finding clues there...

Comment: Strange thing - it does not seem to contain any `CRITICAL` or `ERROR` entries :-/ I assume you tried running the app while `tail` was active? :)

Comment: I ran the app, then executed tail command, and finally  I copied only the logs matching the exec time...

Comment: I'm trying to find out my error, if found I'll let you know, Thanks!

Comment: I have posted some idea for you to try... not sure if it'll help...

Answer (score 1):

```
manyToOne:
    user: <-- CLASS MEMBER NAME
    targetEntity: Users
        joinColumns:
            user: <-- DATABASE COLUMN NAME
                referencedColumnName: id <-- DATABASE COLUMN NAME
```

Be sure that you haven't misplaced `class member name` for `database column name`.

Also, your original `YAML` seems to be a bit more complicated that it should be. As far as I know, `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns` should be used together **only** in case of **joined tabled** (`@ManyToMany`) which is clearly not your case.

The fact that it fails so silently points to some severe error, although I cannot be even guess why it does not log it.

### **EDIT (long shot really):**

Do you, by any chance, have `xdebug` enabled? I've just remembered having some problems with recursion level limit within `xdebug` and `php` terminating silently.

If you do, see this question on how to increase it:
[Increasing nesting function calls limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit)

Comment: Tried this before, using         
user:
            targetEntity: Users
            joinColumns:
                User:
                    referencedColumnName: ID

But still the result is a half-rendered view  Btw thanks for the helping

Comment: Of course, after any change at orm I'm running the db update command succesfully

Comment: Nice, I'm trying. I have news too.. from dev log
 [2014-05-26 17:51:56] emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 107 bytes)
Same kind of msg I'm getting when trying to exec clear cache command. So I'm forced to clear manually the cache folder...

Comment: Yes, I have XDebug enabled ... I think so. I have also checked the datetime issue I got on a twig version, https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/1241  but this not the case...

Comment: I have just change my php.ini memory_limit from 32M to 64M... I'm afraid is not a right solution... and I'd need to optimize doctrine settings... What do you think?

Comment: What it's still strange is getting a similar memory overload while trying to clear cache...

Comment: Should I try to change my doctrine/symfony settings or should I go to increase my php memory limit? The last approach could work on dev but I think that it's not suitable for prod.

Comment: Hm... are you making changes to the right `php.ini`? Some distros have one for command line and one for browser. I've just checked one of my production boxes and it while its memory is set to 128M it performs flawlessly

Comment: I'm on OSX MAMP-File-Edit template-PHP-php.ini. Restart and ok, no problem if I raise the limit. As a better solution I explicit declare every type and  entity options on the form "adds" reducing dramatically the use of memory. Anyway, I'm forced to rely on a 64MB limit, and I don´t know if it's optimized enough.

Comment: Any decent hosting provider supplies you with at least `256M` (don't know about free hostings, though), sooo, you should be fine :)

Comment: I'm at servergrove (developer plan), I'm really glad with them, and the phpinfo() shows 64MB limit.

Answer (score 0):

use mappedBy on the inverse side and inversedBy on the owning side.

venue.orm.yml

```
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: Users
        joinColumns:
                  User:
                      referencedColumnName: ID
        inversedBy:venue
        orphanRemoval: false
```

users.orm.yml

```
oneToMany:
    venue:
        targetEntity: Venues
        joinColumns:
                  Venue:
                      referencedColumnName: ID
        mappedBy: user
        orphanRemoval: false
```

Be careful:

```
joinColumns:
    X:
       referencedColumnName: Y
```

X and Y are sql table fields, X field of Entity field, Y referenced entity field.

Regards