# SymfonyProfiler - Disable annoying "Do you want to open the profiler" JS Alert

Tags: symfony

Sometimes when there is a bug in my Symfony2 Application I will see the regular exception page, this is not a problem, But then about 3 or 4 seconds later a Javascript alert will popup saying something like

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).
>   Do you want to open the profiler?

This is extremely annoying as if I have changed focus to another tab or application it pull focus back to that tab in my browser. The profiler is enabled and usually visible, so why is it not showing on this particular error pages and then showing this annoying JS Alert instead.

Can I disable this alert? I have had looked here
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#profiler

But none of them helped.

(I know I could potentially change settings in my browser or OS but this is the only time JS Alerts are really bothering me)

Answer (score 0):

This usually suggests you have exceeded a recursion (nesting) limit. I think the value of `100` is the default.

Do you happen to use XDebug? If so, this is a well known issue. Read this SO question in order to fix it:

**[Increasing nesting function calls limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit)**

Answer (score 0):

You make this:

In the file:
*./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig*

before:

```
confirm('An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + ').\n\nDo you want to open the profiler?') && (window.location = '{{ path("_profiler", { "token": token }) }}');
```

put "**return**"  like this:

```
function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status !== 0) {
        return;
        confirm('An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + ').\n\nDo you want to open the profiler?') && (window.location = '{{ path("_profiler", { "token": token }) }}');
    }
},
```

or you may redirect this template like: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html

Copy file: 
*./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig*

to:
*./app/Resources/WebProfilerBundle/views/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig*

and modify new file. Add **return** key word.