# symfony2 doctrine - Adding children to self-related Entity

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity which relates to itself. The entity has fields: **parent** and **children**.

```
class A
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var A
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @var A[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $children;
}
```

I want to add children to this entity by setting up children in form.
This entity type looks like this:

```
class AType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('children', 'collection', [
                'type' => new AType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

When I send data like this:

```
'a' => [
    [
        'name' => 'main a',
        'children' => [
            [
                'name' => 'child a 1',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'child a 2',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

(in test, I don't have view, because this application is based on full REST Api communication)
I got this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

So, is it even possible to add children to self-related entities?

It would work if I have 2 entities: entity A with field children related to entity B. But, can it work with this relation?

Should I change **type** in AType class from `new AType()` to something different.

EDIT:
Actually I just want to get data and validate it. I don't need HTML form to display it. I can do it like this:

```
// controller
$jms = $this->get('jms_serializer');
$entity = $jms->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'AcmeBundle\Entity\A', 'json');

$this->em->persist($entity);
$this->em->flush();
```

without using Form in controller. But in this case my data won't be validated.

Comment: Are you trying to serialize your entity at some point? Self reference can cause that and you need to implement your own serialization rules.

Comment: No. I just try to add this and that's it. My action in controller looks totally normal and returns empty response.

Comment: Try to [increase the xdebug value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit/4293870#4293870): `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200`. It should give you the real error.

Comment: That's not a solution. I will see this error even if I set nesting level to 2000. Probably I have to build my own field type.

Comment: @KamilP have you restarted apache after setting xdebug.max_nesting_level ?

Comment: @Sergio Ivanuzzo, yes. But problem occur, because I load AType from AType - it's infinite loop. So I can set event 20000 xdebug.max_nesting_level and it still will appear. I'm looking for different solution.

Answer (score 3):

> PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Because you have recursion. When you call `createForm`, it tries resolve `type`.

You can find this part of code in the `FormFactory` function `resolveType`.

I think you can create second form type which includes `title` and `parent`.

```
class AType extends AbstractType{
   //...
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('parent')
        ->add('children', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new BType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype' => true
        ));
   }
}

class BType extends AbstractType {
    //..
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder
         ->add('title')
         ->add('parent');
    }
 }
```

I think form builder can fetch and map `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I have implemented with html form. Also I have tried to send `application/json` but result is unsuccessful. That's why you can use json schema validators here.

Comment: I was thinking about that. But in this case I can't set up multilevel data. I can set only 2 levels.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to have a look here:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example

The structure id DB relies on other fields stored in DB as well apart from parentID.

It's model is based on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: I may do it, it's not a problem. But in this example they'r base on setting parent. I need to set children, and children of children. And also need to use it with form type.