# Configure PHP in WAMP server xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100

Tags: php, magento, wamp

How do i configure wamp server (windows PC) to debug this errors (in the picture below) while installing Magento?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this suggestion.

Open up your php.ini file in WAMP by clicking on the green W to open the WAMP menu and clicking on PHP=>php.ini. Modify the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level to = 400 or, if this value does not exist, add the following line to your php.ini file:

> xdebug.max_nesting_level = 400;

Restart all services in WAMP.