# Wordpress theme development issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm trying to convert my static theme into WordPress theme, but face this error. how can i resolve this?

[check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIkvL.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand by reading other posts discussing this error. This is an error generated by the xdebug extension. If you can change the setting explained [On xdebug's website](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level) I believe that'll fix that error.

Also: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit) another post discussing a similar (if not same) problem.

EDIT: Could you post some code as well? If your nesting reaches over 400 it would appear that you gotten yourself in a neverending loop.

Answer (score 0):

This error message comes specifically from the XDebug extension.
write following code in your php script .

```
    ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
```

Follow this link . [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit)