# Maximum function nesting level of '415' reached, aborting

Tags: php, loops, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When i set nesting level more than 415 it gives error page is not working and set it by 400 then give error Maximum function nesting level of '415' reached, aborting!

```
function actionIndex(){
    $limit = 1000;
    ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', $limit);
    $queryTopics = "SELECT tr.id,tr.`parent_id`, tr.`child_id`, tr.`order_by`, tr.`level`, tr.`child_id` AS `tid`, t.`name`,t.`seo_name`
                    FROM `topic_relations` tr
                    LEFT JOIN `topics` t ON tr.`child_id` = t.`id`
                    WHERE t.`status` = 1";
    $topicss = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($queryTopics)->queryAll();
    $topics = array();
    foreach ($topicss as $key => $value) {
        $parentIdCombination = $this->findAllParent($value['id']);
        $combination = array_reverse($parentIdCombination);
        $combinations = implode($combination, ' ');
        $topics['parent_combination'] = $combinations;
        unset($combination);
        $topics[] = $value;
    }
    $data['topicsParentChildArr'] = $this->buildTopicsTree($topics);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($topics);
    return $this->render('index',['data'=>$data]);
}
```

this function call recursively

```
function findAllParent($id) {
    global $combination;
    $parentTopicQuery =  "SELECT * FROM `topic_relations` where id=".$id;
    $topic_row = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($parentTopicQuery)->queryOne();

    if($topic_row['level']>0) {
        $combination[] = $topic_row['child_id'];
        $parentTopicQuery1 =  "SELECT * FROM `topic_relations` where child_id=".$topic_row['parent_id'];
        $topic_row1 = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($parentTopicQuery)->queryOne();
        $this->findAllParent($topic_row1['id']);
    }else {
        $combination[] = $topic_row['child_id'];
    }
    //var_dump($combination);
    return $combination;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? And if this a production site, why are you running xdebug in it?

Comment: How can increase the maximum nesting loop level??

Comment: you need to change it on php.ini its called `xdebug.max_nesting_level` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-function-calls-limit

Comment: i did but its not working for me.

Comment: @InusSaha [`xdebug.max_nesting_level` is `PHP_INI_ALL`](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/xdebug.c#L349) so setting it via `ini_set` like the OP did should work

Comment: Asking again: do you need xdebug for something? if you dont need it, uninstall the extension and the error will be gone and your site about 400% faster.

Comment: I think this is a case of a typo: the innermost query is actually executing the outer query, not the inner one. The inner one should read `createCommand($parentTopicQuery1)` instead of `createCommand($parentTopicQuery)` (note the "1"). Because of this, the code will recurse for ever until an error occurs. I vote to close as typo.

Comment: If it's looping 415 times, this is more likely a recursive error.  Increasing the limit isn't a solution more a hope that it works for now.

Comment: so was it a typo error as mentioned by trincot ? or that was because it was typed in here? although he sounds logical

Answer (score 1):

There's no such limitaiton in PHP. The max function nesting level is a limitation of the xdebug extension.

If you want/need to increase this, just change the php.ini setting `xdebug.max_nesting_level`. I.e. you could use `2000`.

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 2000
```

I have to mention, that this only applies for your development server. On production environments, there should never be the xdebug extension installed.

Comment: if i set it more than 415 it gives page is not working error, as i mention in my question.

Comment: php.ini, and also change in function.