# symfony4.4 use monolog mailer occurs error [ Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting ]

Tags: php, symfony, mailer, monolog

**I refer to the doc of [How to Configure Monolog to Email Errors] (symfony version 4.4)**

[docs link](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/logging/monolog_email.html)

**Occurs error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached**

```
!!  Error {#5035
!!    #message: "Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached,         
aborting!"
!!    #code: 0
!!    #file: "C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment- api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php"
!!    #line: 3137
!!    trace: {
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:3137 {
!!        ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->ContainerOsYVzcc\{closure}
!!        ›
!!        › return $this->privates['mailer.mailer'] = new 
\Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer((new \Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport(new RewindableGenerator(function () {
!!        ›     yield 0 => ($this->privates['mailer.transport_factory.null'] ?? $this->getMailer_TransportFactory_NullService());
!!      }
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Argument\RewindableGenerator.php:35 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport.php:143 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport.php:134 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport.php:86 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport.php:78 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:3141 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:3658 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:3642 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:1600 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:3155 { …}
!!      C:\work\gitlab\pay\payment-api\var\cache\dev\ContainerOsYVzcc\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:3138 { …}
```

**How to resolve ? Who can help me**

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-function-calls-limit

Answer (score 1):

It's a **xdebug issue** since PHP do not have a Maximum function nesting level

try setting:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000
```

in your **php.ini** ( or disable xdebug )